# upgrade postgis extension to 2.5.1

Tags: postgis

I need to update postgis extenstion from 2.4.5 to 2.5.1. When I use command:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

I got the following message:
version "2.4.5" of extension "postgis" is already installed.

Specifying 2.5.1 version directly:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE to "2.5.1";
```

results in the following response:

ERROR: extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.4.5" to version "2.5.1"

My PostgreSQL version is 11.1

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: Thank you, the problem is fixed.

Comment: @chekhovana can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: The problem was solved by upgrading operating system. I don't know details, because my colleague did it.